Session crashes back logon screen
RESOLVED*** sort of.  This issue seems to be with VMWare Workstation v17.5.1.  I backed down to v17.0 and the problem is gone.
***UPDATE.  I am now certain this issue is being caused by VMWare Workstation Pro 17 because it has now escalated. Now my entire system crashes every time I launch a VM.  I can start Workstation Pro but it crashes when I launch the actual VM.   It has worked since I built this machine in March with the sporatic issues that may have started when I moved from Gnome to KDE Plasma.  Now I cannot launch a VM at all.  I have launched in Gnome and KDE and its the same.  System locks or reboots when I launch a VM.  I tried multiple VMs stored on different drives.  Same result.
Running 22.04LTS and periodically my session freezes for a few seconds and flashes back to the logon screen and restarts the session in the process. More often this happens when the PC is idle but will happen while I am working also.  I am running VMWare regularly and I am starting to believe this might be involved.  I am not sure what to look for in what log to isolate this and would appreciate any pointers.
This is a fairly high end build
I9-14700 processor
AMD Radeon RC7800XT
96 GB RAM
A minimal amount of resources are allocated to the VM 2CPUs 2 Cores/32GB RAM
Appreciate whatever you might offer.
Thanks.

Check dmesg (usually hardware logs)or journalctl -r (usually software logs, -r shows newest first) for errors.
